# Moments of Markov chains.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

I am working with a discrete Markov chain $X_0,X_1,...$ with state space $(-1,1)$ and
transition matrix.
\begin{align} P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1-\alpha & \alpha \\
    \beta & 1-\beta
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
where $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$. This Markov chain has a steady-state distribution $\left(\pi_{0}, \pi_{1}\right) = \left( \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}, \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\right)$. I am looking for a simple way to calculate moments of the form
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[X_i X_j X_k X_l \right]
\end{align}
under the assumption of stationarity, where $i < j < k < l$. I am aware that these moments can be calculated by conditioning in turn on $X_i$, $X_j$, $X_k$ and $X_l$, but this requires summing 16 products of 4 transition probabilities each. I was hoping there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need to compute those moments? Is there a model-interpretation or is it just plain curiosity?